# How to pass a parameter from method in DAO to SQL query?

Tags: android, sql, kotlin, dao

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT number FROM ${DBTables.SAVED_INPUTS} WHERE number LIKE ':input%'")
fun getSavedInputs(input : String) : List<SavedInput>
```

This is not working though... I want to pass in that input from method to my query

Comment: What result are you getting back, and is there an error message?

Comment: Yes,  error: Unused parameter: input

Answer (score 1):

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT number FROM ${DBTables.SAVED_INPUTS} WHERE number LIKE :input%")
```

fun getSavedInputs(input : String) : List

Turned out to be this